# How can I commit and push just one changed file with Olive?

Tags: linux, version-control, bazaar, launchpad

Using [Olive](https://launchpad.net/bzr-gtk) on Linux I have changed a number of files on my local system. Normally I would do `Branch>Commit` followed by `Branch>Push`, but in this case I only want to place one of the changes on [lp:stevedore](https://code.launchpad.net/~stevedore-developers/stevedore/trunk) at this time. How can I commit and push just one of the changed files but not all of the other changes?

Answer (score 3):

On the command line, you should be able to do

```
> cd <path to working tree>
> bzr commit -m "<commit message>" <relative path to file>
```

in order to commit only the changes to the file specified.

So, supposing your working tree is `~/code`, and `bzr status` looks something like

```
modified:
  README
  dir/file0.py
  dir/file1.py
```

you can `bzr commit -m "File0 changes" dir/file0.py` to commit only the changes to *file1.py*.

FWIW, bzr-qt provides `qcommit`, which shows all files to be committed with a checkbox for each so you can easily choose a subset of files to commit.  Perhaps bzr-gtk provides something similar?

Comment: bzr-qt is actually named QBzr.